# Meta Attribute in Asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, meta-attribute

I was wondering what the logic is behind meta attribute. For example in asp.net for localization we can use something like this to localize a control :

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="DefaultText" 
meta:resourcekey="Button1" />
```

So what's the logic of  `meta:resourcekey="Button1"`.Is there any different usage of meta tags like in this example ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For hiding your asp.net tag attribute from HTML output**

You have an attribute and you want to hide this attribute in your HTML output . It useful when you dont want extra junk in your response then  use “meta:”

Example:

```
<asp:Label id="myLabel" runat="server"  text=”hello”  myattribute="mello"  />
```

Output is

```
<span myattribute="mello">hello </span>
```

**with using meta:**

```
<asp:Label id="myLabel" runat="server"  text="hello"  meta:myattribute="mello"  />
```

output is

```
<span>hello</span>
```

[Source](http://bpostaci.wordpress.com/2010/01/22/hide-your-asp-net-tag-attribute-from-html-output/)